# Json post from input or textfield

Tags: java, php, json, curl

I'm new and I need some help.

I have a script that can change an advert in some API. If we turn it one, a total area in advert id 14214 will change on "100", it works fine.

```
<?php 
    $url = "http://test.com/update";

    $data = array (
    userId                          =>      MYID, // authentication userId
    loginToken                      =>      'MYTOKEN', // authentication loginToken
    "id"                            =>      "14214",
    "totalArea"                     =>      "100"
    );

     $data_string = http_build_query($data);
     $ch = curl_init();
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
     $result = curl_exec($ch);
     curl_close($ch); 
     print_r ($result);

    ?>
```

What I need is to use textfield or input to change it in other way.

I have a textfield or input with some value, I need to click a button to turn one script with this value pasted in "100" in totalArea, without refreshing the page.

Any ideas?

Comment: check ajax and learn it

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use javascript and an ajax call that will run the async and on success return a response.

something like

```
     $('#form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); // stope form from submitting
        var $formValues = { 'id' => $('#field') }; //gather data into an object


        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: youurl.com,
          data: $formValues
          }).onsuccess(function(data){
             // return some success notification
           });
     });
```

This is not 100% perfect but should get you along the right lines

great reference is http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: Matthew I need to paste to json a value from texfield, not paste something to textfield.

Comment: The above advice is fine just ignore setting the value from the onsuccess, but i recommend still having this as it will allow you to handle errors by adding another chained event

Comment: Thank you. Are you able to write full code from <?php  to ?> with button and f.ex two textfields and two json values, fex. "totalArea" and "totalArea2"?

Comment: Yes I can but it will cost you ;)